# Excel Find/Replace Macro one step further

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I use excel to store links. Inside those links i have some parts that i want edit (i do that with find/replace macro) and some that i want to delete, however Find and Replace can't delete random codes.

An example is : lty=1&rc=fpcDlkseLz4&ra

What i want macro to remove is "rc=xxxxxxxxxxx&" for all links, with the random code able to take digits,letters upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try below non-vba solution

```
  =MID(A1,1,FIND("rc=",A1,1)-1)&RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND("&",A1,FIND("rc=",A1,1))))
```

[image]